# SharePoint 2007 form, with data inserted into SQL

Tags: php, sql, forms, sharepoint-2007, infopath

I'm setting up a form on an internal Sharepoint 2007 site, and the requestor would like the form data to emailed to them, and stored on a SQL Server table.

I have a good general knowledge of web development, but I am relatively new to developing for SharePoint, and it's not within budget for me to learn Visual Studio and C# and make a webpart.

So, I am attemping to do this with a basic HTML form within a Page Viewer webpart, posting to a PHP script & handling the email and SQL insert in PHP. The problem is that upon hitting submit, rather than executing the PHP script, it hides the form and displays the PHP code in plain text in the webpart.

Now, I know I'm not using PHP correctly for SharePoint, but I cannot find any information on how to run PHP within SharePoint, other than people using PHP on a seperate server to pull list data.

Anyone have any ideas on a fix, or an alternative method of achieving this kind of form?

I am open to trying new things, but I will NOT build a webpart, especially as this should be portable, as we're upgrading SP soon and moving to a new server.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may be able to use InfoPath to accomplish this.
Please see the following link for an InfoPath introduction - http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/introduction-to-microsoft-office-infopath-2007-HA010163577.aspx